# DELETE record from the ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have created a kafka topic and a schema for a table.
The retention time for topic is by default 7 days. But in the ksqlDB, The record is being appended again and again and the older records are in ksqlDB. I want to delete the older records from the table also.
I am not able to auto delete those records.

How to autodelete records from the kSql table?

I tried a lot and tried to find everywhere but not able to find any solution on it to auto delete the records from the Ksql table after retention period.

Answer (score 0):

Ksql doesn't "append records". Your producer does...

Records in Kafka topics are immutable, and cannot be deleted.

To remove keys *from a KTable*, you need to produce a record with a null value for a given key; it will not be automatic, and KTables are built from compacted topics, so retention times do not apply